# File Handling in Perl: Reading a file from a specific line

Tags: perl, file-io, scripting

Is there no way in perl to start reading a file from a specific line number. Whenever we read a file in perl we do `while(<$fileHandler>)` which makes the perl interpreter to read the file from beginning. What to do if I don't want to read these lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can skip lines from the beginning, and start processing with `$start_line`,

```
my $start_line = 10;
while(<$fileHandler>) {
  next unless $. == $start_line .. undef;

  # ..
}
```

The [`range operator ..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) also provides the following shorthand:

> If either operand of scalar ".." is a constant expression, that operand is considered true if it is equal (`==`) to the current input line number (the `$.` variable).

Therefore the above can be reduced to:

```
while(<$fileHandler>) {
  next unless 10 .. undef;

  # ..
}
```

Comment: @JohnC yes; it only shows how to effectively skip the lines.

Comment: OMG!  This may be one of the few times I'm actually cool with the use of [`unless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unless.html).  It's so rare that I forget examples.  Thanks for sharing  ;)

Comment: @Miller I didn't believe myself what did I just wrote. ;) btw, `if not` still does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't know how long a line will be you must read from the beginning of the file.

If you know how wide your line will be because you have a fixed line width, or some other scheme then you can seek to that position in your file.  Otherwise you have to read every character and search for the 'special' new line characters.

A text file is just a long list of characters.  There is nothing special about lines.

Comment: This is not a problem specific to Perl as the OP's question implies.

Comment: Yes it's not specific to perl but it's a good explanation of the problem :)