# Perl Flip Flop operator and line numbers

Tags: perl, operators, flip-flop

I noticed this while looking at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24105098/1733163)...

If I have a script like this:

```
while (<>) {
  print if 5 .. undef;
}
```

It skips lines 1..4 then prints the rest of the file.
However if I try this:

```
my $start_line = 5;
while (<>) {
  print if $start_line .. undef;
}
```

It prints from line 1.
Can anyone explain why?

Actually I'm not even sure why the first one works.

Hmmm looking further into this I found that this works:

```
my $start = 5;
while (<>) {
  print if $. ==  $start .. undef;
}
```

So the first version magically uses `$.` which is the line number.  But I don't know why it fails with a variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use of a bare number in the flip-flop is treated as a test against the line count variable, `$.`. From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> If either operand of scalar `".."` is a ***constant expression***, that
>   operand is considered true if it is equal (`==`) to the current input
>   line number (the `$.` variable).

So

```
print if 5 .. undef;
```

is "shorthand" for:

```
print if $. == 5 .. undef;
```

---

The same is not true for a scalar variable as it is *not* a constant expression. This is why it is not tested against `$.`.

Comment: Perl is sometimes more like a 'magic spell book' than a language.

Comment: @JohnC : That is even truer for the English language :)